# Examples of openly accessible field or farm-level soil acidity (pH) data?

Tags: data-request, agriculture

Can anyone provide examples of openly accessible field or farm-level soil acidity (pH) data? Ideally for one or more locations in New Zealand, the UK or Australia?

Answer (score 2):

For the United Kingdom, you can access soil pH through the [United Kingdom Soil Observatory](http://www.ukso.org/)

[image: UKSO viewer showing pH level data]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too broad a scale:
[ASRIS - Australian Soil Resource Information System - National Soil Grids](http://www.asris.csiro.au/themes/NationalGrids.html)
for Australia